# update svn in windows explorer address bar, how to keep CMD open

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, tortoise-svn

This is a **very** common question. Here's a new spin to it:

I usually run commands directly in windows explorer windows (i.e. where you type the path in windows explorer). I often find myself typing e.g. `svn update` but then can't read the ouput. Unfortunately common fixes like `svn update & pause` or `&& pause` don't seem to have any effect.

**why is this?** And what could a possible fix be without registry modifications?

Answer (score 2):

Commands you type in the address bar are not executed from within a 'DOS prompt', so `pause`, which is a DOS command, is never going to work. It's basically the same as typing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, and then running the `pause` command. Try it and you will see what I mean.

There are some workarounds though:

One way would be to type `cmd /k svn update`. The *cmd* command starts a DOS prompt, and specifying the */k* parameter will cause it to not be closed after the command is executed. Run `cmd /h` from a command prompt to see help about all parameters.

Another option is to create a batch file containing the commands, e.g.

```
svn update
pause
```

and then run that batch file from the address bar.

A third idea: Just type `cmd`, and keep the command prompt open as long as you need it. This has the advantage that you can use the command history. For instance type <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> to repeat the last command.

Comment: awesome, can you quickly save readers a google and explain `cmd /k?`

Comment: did quickly google it: 
`CMD /C    Run Command and then terminate
 ::
CMD /K    Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
          This is useful for testing, to examine variables`

Comment: @user2305193 Good point, I added a short explanation.

Comment: any more resources on the differences between cmd and 'run' would be helpful, but I guess googling (knowing there is a fundamental difference) already helps